# Linq2Db: How to use function Sql.Ext.ListAgg?

Tags: c#, db2, linq2db

I have a model with table Position where are multiple rows with same column value CompanyId and I'd like to group these rows and concat another column Email into comma separated list.

My database is IBM DB2 for i and in SQL I can write query like this:

```
SELECT 
  CompanyId, 
  ListAgg(Email, ',') within group (order by Email) as Emails
FROM Postion
GROUP BY CompanyId
```

I'm trying to retype the query above to [Linq2DB](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) with additional provider [LinqToDb4iSeries](https://github.com/LinqToDB4iSeries/Linq2DB4iSeries) but without success. The first property GroupedEmails1 builds query without statement "group by", the second one GroupedEmails2 builds nested subquery with group by and parent query with ListAgg - both of them fail to work.

```
public class Position {
  public int CompanyId { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataConection : DataConnection {
  public ITable<Position> Positions => GetTable<Position>();

  public IQueryable<object> GroupedEmails1 => Position
    .Select(p => new {
      p.CompanyId
      Emails = Sql.Ext.ListAgg(p.Email, ",").WithinGroup.OrderBy(p.Email).ToValue()
    });

  public IQueryable<object> GroupedEmails2 => Position
    .GroupBy(p => p.CompanyId)
    .SelectMany(g => g.Select(p => new { CompanyId = g.Key, Email = p.Email }))
    .Select(p => new {
      p.CompanyId
      Emails = Sql.Ext.ListAgg(p.Email, ",").WithinGroup.OrderBy(p.Email).ToValue()
    });
}
```

Does anybody have an experience with Linq2Db "Sql.Ext.*" aggregate functions?

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution for my question above ... maybe it will help someone.

There is an extension method called StringAggregate that is translated into sql function LISTAGG.

```
public class Position {
  public int CompanyId { get; set; }
  public string Email { get; set; }
}

public class MyDataConection : DataConnection {
  public ITable<Position> Positions => GetTable<Position>();

  public IQueryable<object> GroupedEmails1 => Position
    .GroupBy(p => p.CompanyId)
    .Select(g => new {
      CompanyId = g.Key,
      Emails = g.StringAggregate(",", x => x.Email).OrderBy(x => x.Email).ToValue()
    });
}
```

Comment: You are right. But create issue in GitHub that `ListAgg` is not ready for grouping.